# Why can't my digital multimeter read resistance?

Tags: led, diodes, resistance, multimeter

My multimeter can read voltage (AC and DC), current, but it can't read resistance or diode.

When you set it on resistance it will always show 1, same thing for diode check. It was working fine until yesterday. I opened it but couldn't find anything blown inside. I really don't know what happened to my brand new multimeter. [image]

Comment: Doesn't that just mean the resistance is over the limit? Can you edit your question to add a picture of your multimeter?

Comment: Short the probes together. What does it read now?

Comment: Hi, Luka. It should be pretty clear to you that you have left out all sorts of information such as the make, model, link to user manual and a photo of your test procedure. Have you ever successfully made a resistance measurement on another meter? Did you read the manual? How exactly did you measure current? Did you use the amps mode to short out a battery or mains supply?

Comment: Need more info. One potential issue is you use different jacks on the meter for measuring voltage/resistance versus current.

Comment: N.B. Get into the habit of taking the lead out of the current measuring jack as soon as you've finished measuring current. Otherwise you could absent-mindedly put a short circuit across something, which often ends badly.

Comment: What was it that you did to your meter yesterday?

Comment: Hi to all of you. Multimeter is: Digital Multimeter DT830B. It reads voltage, and current. I read user manual. But it cant read resistance. I have one resisistor of 10 ohms(i read it from color code). I select limit on 200ohm on multimeter and it is showing 1 all of time, when resistor is or isnt connetdet to probes, 1 is on LCD screen. When a short the probes it remaims 1 on screen. I have one COM jack, one VOhmsmA and one for 10ADC. Measuring procedure is correct everytime but there isn't any result on the screen. I replaced battery, but still nothing.

Comment: It also cant do diode check. I switch do diode sign, red probe to anode, black on catode and nothing, diode doesn't light. When I was switching battery a look on electronics inside multimeter. All was fine, nothing burned or something like that. I was doing on my project, and multimeter was fine, it could test resistors,led diodeals, voltage... Then, when i woke up, I went to my garage, turn on multimeter and it doesn't read resistance and led diodes, just voltage and current. When I select voltage on tje acreen there is 000, and for resiatance there is 1.I add to my question picture of Multim

Comment: Wow, this thing has voltages and mA measurements on the same port ! This design optimizes the likelihood of blowing up the meter. What a strange design requirement from the manufacturer....

Comment: If shorting the probes does not give you a near-zero reading, return the multimeter as broken.

Comment: Thank you for answers. Im gonna keep multimeter because it can show voltage. Im gonna wait and see what will happen to intrument by the time, because it broke up over the night by itself somehow, so maybe it will be fixd by itself, hahhaah. Im joking ofc, but definitly gonna keep instrument. Once more thank you to all of you